# Docker nginx + php replied 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I have this issue while i want to test my PHP project containerized. So I have installed docker on my laptop (the version included below) and then i create nginx container with php info file attach to `/usr/share/nginx/html`. But when i checked the result, i got the 403 Forbidden. I've tried to convert the php info file into the HTML file, it works fine ! But when i change it back to php info, i got the 403 Forbidden. I've also tried to install php and php-fpm on the container itself. But nothing change. Can you guys help me out.

This is my `docker version` output

```
versionClient: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.5
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        55c4c88
 Built:             Tue Mar  2 20:18:20 2021
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.5
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       363e9a8
  Built:            Tue Mar  2 20:16:15 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.4
  GitCommit:        05f951a3781f4f2c1911b05e61c160e9c30eaa8e
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc93
  GitCommit:        12644e614e25b05da6fd08a38ffa0cfe1903fdec
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

this is the php info file located in `/home/taufik/Documents/praktikum/docker/30-mar-2021/sosial-media/html`

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

and this is my docker command to run the nginx container

```sh
docker run -it --rm -dp 8080:80 --name=nginx -v $(pwd):/usr/share/nginx/html /home/taufik/html nginx
```

this is the log of the nginx container

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
,/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
,/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
,10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
,10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
,/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
,/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
,/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
,2021/03/30 09:33:02 [error] 32#32: *1 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "0.0.0.0:8080", referrer: "http://0.0.0.0:9000/"
,172.17.0.1 - - [30/Mar/2021:09:33:02 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 555 "http://0.0.0.0:9000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36" "-"
,
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error:

```
2021/03/30 09:33:02 [error] 32#32: *1 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "0.0.0.0:8080", referrer: "http://0.0.0.0:9000/"
```

sounds like your php file is not an `index.php` and you're trying to access the server at `/`, without the name of the file. It then tries to show you the directory listing (all content in the directory you mounted at `/usr/share/nginx/html/` but the default config doesn't allow that. Hence the 403 because the config forbids showing the directory listing.

Try accessing the file with its name directly. Something like `localhost:8080/filename.php` should work.

#### However

If you're just using the nginx container, that alone won't let you execute php scripts as it's only nginx, no fpm whatsoever.

There are two ways to fix this:

1. If you want something simple, just use the `php:apache` image and mount your php files to `/var/www/html/` into the container. The command would look something like this: `docker run -it --rm -dp 8080:80 --name=nginx -v $(pwd):/var/www/html php:apache`
2. Use the `php:fpm` image in combination with an nginx container. Slightly more complicated as you will need a custom config for the nginx container as well.

Generally speaking, the docker way of doing things™ is to have one container for each service, hence an fpm and nginx container. You wouldn't install fpm into the nginx container.

I'd reccommend you to look into how docker containers interact and can be made to work together.

Comment: Thanks kolaente, your solution seems to work. Case closed

Comment: In my case the 403 error was misleading... the root cause was that my /usr/share/nginx/html/ directory was empty.